# Count all if even zero

Tags: sql

I have this SQL

```
SELECT count(*) AS TotalOrders, [Sell-to Customer No_], [Document Date] 
FROM [Navision4].[dbo].[3S Company A_S$Sales Invoice Header]  
  INNER JOIN [Navision4].[dbo].[3s Statusboard Customer]
    ON [Navision4].[dbo].[3S Company A_S$Sales Invoice Header].[Sell-to Customer No_] = [Navision4].[dbo].[3s Statusboard Customer].[No_] 
WHERE [Document Date] <= '2015-09-25'
GROUP BY [Sell-to Customer No_], [Document Date]
```

But it's not does what i want do.

Example:

If I have 3 items in [Navision4].[dbo].[3s Statusboard Customer].[No_]

```
[No_]   
10
20
30
```

But in my table [Navision4].[dbo].[3S Company A_S$Sales Invoice Header] are only records for Customer 10 and 20.

I have no records for customer 30 and this will not be returned. 
But i want my SQL to return 0 for customer 30 and not hide it.

How can I do that?

Hope i make sense :)

Comment: Try LEFT JOIN instead of JOIN.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using (which is presumably SQL Server).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to count the number of invoices for a customer on each day. If a customer doesn't have any invoices, then you'll need to do a left join, joining the invoices table to the customer table like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d7cb3a/6. In case of null date, select 0, otherwise count(*).

```
select customer.id, invoice.dt,
case when invoice.dt is null then 0 else count(*) end as TotalOrders
from customer
left join invoice
on invoice.customer = customer.id
and invoice.dt <= '2015-09-25'
group by customer.id, invoice.dt
```

If you're trying to find the total number of invoices for a customer, then take the date out of the select statement and group by clause like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d7cb3a/11

```
select customer.id,
case when invoice.customer is null then 0 else count(*) end as TotalOrders
from customer
left join invoice
on invoice.customer = customer.id
and invoice.dt <= '2015-09-25'
group by customer.id, invoice.customer
order by customer.id
```

Notice that I've included invoice.customer in the group by clause so that you can check that field for NULL.

I'm assuming that you can translate my sample table names back to your database structure.

Answer (score 0):

You need an outer join.  If `Document Date` is in the customer table:

```
SELECT count(*) AS TotalOrders, c.[No_], [Document Date] 
FROM [Navision4].[dbo].[3s Statusboard Customer] c LEFT JOIN
     [Navision4].[dbo].[3S Company A_S$Sales Invoice Header] s
     ON s.[Sell-to Customer No_] = c.[No_] 
WHERE c.[Document Date] <= '2015-09-25'
GROUP BY c.[No_], [Document Date] ;
```

Otherwise, you need to move the condition to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT count(*) AS TotalOrders, c.[No_], [Document Date] 
FROM [Navision4].[dbo].[3s Statusboard Customer] c LEFT JOIN
     [Navision4].[dbo].[3S Company A_S$Sales Invoice Header] s
     ON s.[Sell-to Customer No_] = c.[No_] AND
        s.[Document Date] <= '2015-09-25'
GROUP BY c.[No_], [Document Date] ;
```

Notice that the table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: Thank, but I cant get it to work. I got one record where the TotalOrders is 1. But not get my No_ 30 and a zero (0)